# Trigger with requirements

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I got 2 tables a People Table and a vehicle Table , the vehicle table as a Foreign key called Owner (proprietario in the code)  referencing people.id (p.id in code)

I want to create a trigger that when a person ( in table pessoa) has 5 vehicles , the insertion or update will be ignored. The Query works. The trigger not really.

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_owner() RETURNS trigger as $trigger_owner$
BEGIN
     IF (SELECT  count(p.id) as NoCars
        FROM pessoa p , veiculo v 
        WHERE p.id = v.proprietario and v.proprietario  = NEW.proprietario
        GROUP BY p.id) 
     >= 5
        RAISE EXCEPTION '% owner cant have more than 20 vehicles', NEW.proprietario;
    END IF
END;

$trigger_owner$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`CREATE TRIGGER trigger_owner BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON veiculo FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trigger_owner();`

Theres an error when running :
ERROR: missing "THEN" in the end of the SQL expression

I could add a Then but not sure what commands i would have to put so that the insertion/update is ignored

Comment: What happens when you add `THEN` after `5`? If you raise an exception, the insert will be rolled back.

Comment: Read this [plpgsql Conditionals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) section of the docs.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i think i've managed to do it. Thanks

Comment: @Bohemian  I answered the question , is Return null an overkill to RAISE EXCEPTION?

Comment: Return null aborts the insert/update

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_owner() RETURNS trigger as $trigger_owner$
BEGIN
     IF (SELECT  count(p.id) as NoCars
        FROM pessoa p , veiculo v 
        WHERE p.id = v.proprietario and v.proprietario  = NEW.proprietario
        GROUP BY p.id) 
     >= 20
         THEN RAISE NOTICE 'id % owner cant have more than 20 vehicles', NEW.proprietario;
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
   
END;
$trigger_owner$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_owner BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON veiculo
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trigger_owner();
```

Comment: The `RETURN NULL;` is going to abort the action, so this `RAISE EXCEPTION` does not really add anything. It should probably be changed to `RAISE NOTICE` for logging/notification purposes.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The thing is if i remove return null and leave raise exception only , the insertion proceeds on.

Comment: 1) I said change `RAISE EXCEPTION` to `RAISE NOTICE`, nothing about removing `RETURN NULL`. 2) The only way the INSERT proceeds with `RAISE EXCEPTION` is when then `IF ... THEN` is false and you go straight to `RETURN NEW;`